# Compute $\int_{A}^{B}\prod_i \frac{(x-A_i)^{\alpha_i-1}(B_i-x)^{\beta_i-1}}{(B_i-A_i)^{\alpha_i+\beta_i-1}\mathrm{B}(\alpha_i,\beta_i)}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, definite-integrals

I need a fast and accurate method to evaluate numerically the following integral:

$$I=\int_{A}^{B}\prod_{i}\frac{(x-A_{i})^{\alpha_{i}-1}(B_{i}-x)^{\beta_{i}-1}}{(B_{i}-A_{i})^{\alpha_{i}+\beta_{i}-1}\mathrm{B}(\alpha_{i},\beta_{i})}\mathrm{d}x$$

where $i$ takes the values $1,2,..$ up to a finite positive integer. All the numbers are real, and $A=\max_i A_i$, $B=\min_i B_i$. Assume that $A\le B$. Also, $\alpha_i,\beta_i > 0$ for all $i$.

$\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)$ is the Beta function.

Comment: If I may ask, where did you find this monster ? By the way, what is $B(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)$ is the Beta function. I was playing with integrals related to Beta distributions, and this came up. I came up with a somewhat good numerical algorithm to compute this, but it is somewhat complicated and fails and/or takes too long in some cases to give and accurate result. I could post the algorithm I have now (it is complicated, but I'll probably post it later), but I don't think it will contribute much, and I want to hear fresh ideas.

Answer (score 1):

First, to state the obvious, the denominator should only be evaluated once:

$$ I=\int_A^B \left(\Pi_i \frac{1}{(B_i-A_i)^{\alpha_i+\beta_i-1}B(\alpha_i,\beta_i)}\right) \Pi_i (x-A_i)^{\alpha_i-1}(B_i-x)^{\beta_i-1}\mathrm{d}x$$

This integral seems suitable for the double-exponential transformation method (DOI: 10.1016/S0377-0427(00)00501-X). There are a number of code implementations out there already, e.g.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31550/Fast-Numerical-Integration

In practice you pick a transformation $x=\phi(t)$ with $a=\phi(-\infty)$ and $b=\phi(\infty)$ such that

$$ |f(\phi(t))\phi^\prime(t)|\approx\exp(-c\exp|t|),\quad |t|\to\infty $$

Your integral then becomes

$$ I=\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\phi(t))\phi^\prime(t)\mathrm{d}t \approx h\sum_{k=-N_{-}}^{N_{+}} f(\phi(hk))\phi^\prime(kh) $$

where the final summation is evaluated using the standard trapezoidal rule.

The form of $\phi(t)$ is somewhat arbitrary but for a finite interval $(a,b)$ a common choice is

$$ \phi(t) = \frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}\tanh\left[\frac{\pi}{2}\sinh(t)\right] $$

Comment: Thanks for the link ! It just looks fascinating. Cheers :)

Comment: True that the denominator can be evaluated only once. But it is important to leave inside the integrand, to avoid overflows.

Comment: +1 But this method needs a transformation function $x=phi(t)$. Any ideas on how I can choose a good one, given the form of my integrand?

Comment: @becko I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But I had already seen that transformation. I was wondering if a better transformation $\phi(t)$ (which would require less function evaluations) could be given, since we know the form of the integrand.

Comment: @becko Oh I see. Well I'm not sure what properties $\phi(t)$ would need to have to make it "better" so I'll have to bow out and let someone smarter pick that one up.

Comment: A desirable property is that the $N_- + N_+ + 1$ function evaluations should cover as best as possible the region near the maximum of the integrand, without having to resort to a small value of $h$. This is achieved through adequate selection of $\phi (t)$.